# why fql statement false but still run?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square 
FROM user
WHERE uid=1060857175 
   or uid=1065687593 
   or uid=1112477665
   or uid=1198862928
   or uid=1228172806
   or uid=100000296599460ORDER BY name
LIMIT 2
OFFSET 1
```

I want to ask questions when I use fql wrong but still runs (ORDER BY not space). please help me explain why run ok. facebook parse?

Comment: @Nathan when you edited the query you changed the part that was supposed to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I will rely on good ol' [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor): What you posted *is not* invalid FQL.